# Pull out the specific word from title name and insert it anywhere on view page?

Tags: magento-1.9

We use Magento 1.9 and we have the following name for product name:

"Laptop Gaming MSI Bravo 17 A4DDR-057XRO AMD Ryzen 7 4800H pana la 4.20 GHz, 17.3", Full HD, 144Hz, 8GB, 512GB SSD [NEW]"

We call above product name with the following code:

```
<?php echo $_product->getName()?>
```

This last word in bracket "[NEW]" we would like to pull out (if possible) and insert it in other place on our view page!

Any suggestion how this can be accomplished? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it would be to create an attribute assigned to catalog products that allowed you to specify a product tag (New, Discounted, Bargain).

This way you can drop the [NEW] tag from the product name and you the you can access that attribute to do whatever you want.

```
<?php print $_product->getAttributeText('the_attribute_you_created'); ?>
<?php print $_product->getName(); ?>
```